# When detect in/outgoing call in android phone i want to send a sms to my parent number

Tags: android, android-intent

i am trying to develop a android application using broadcast receiver,my application means   that,first i want to define and store a PARENT number to the database on my first activity   ,when we install the app this activity will launch and the parent number saved to the   database,then broadcast receiver want to active and its listen for call state   changing,if   any call is make through that phone i want to send a message to the parent   number...??...here how can i use broadcast receiver...is it possible...and i mentioning my   codes below......i hope you can help me for this .i try  to do this many ways but i cant   get the result.here first i create my first activity inside that i accessing my database   values and trying to activate broadcast receiver.

```
    public class PARENT_CALLActivity extends Activity 
{

    String PARENT=null;
    EditText edparent;
    Button submit;
    String parent_number;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        edparent=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);


        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                PARENT=edparent.getText().toString();   

                MyDabasehandler db=new MyDabasehandler(getApplicationContext());

                if(db.getContact().equals(null))
                {
                    db.addContact(new Contacts(PARENT));

                }
                else
                {
                    db.editContact();
                }
             Intent reciver=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),myBroadcast.class);
             startActivity(reciver);
            }

        });       
    }
}
```

**my broadcast receiver....**

```
     public class myBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    String out_number;
    String myparent;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     out_number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

    MyDabasehandler db=new MyDabasehandler(context);

    myparent=db.getContact().toString();

        //Toast.makeText(context, out_number+"number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        SmsManager sm=SmsManager.getDefault();
          sm.sendTextMessage(myparent, "5554", "calling..to"+out_number, null, null);//5554 is my emulator number to check its in emulator
        Toast.makeText(context, "send"+out_number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }


}
```

**and my Manifest is..**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="sha.pcall"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".PARENT_CALLActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MyDabasehandler"
        android:label="@string/app_name">       
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Contacts"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".myBroadcast"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />                
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 

    </application>
/manifest>
```

**and i am getting force to close when i press the submit button.**

Comment: You should put the exception StackTrace as well to know the reason of the FC

Comment: @paresh Myani :thank you for your comment i solve that FC problem......can u tell me how can i access my database value to broadcast receiver activity...i cant read that on there...plse go through it..my code is..public Cursor getContact() 
 {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  
  Cursor contacts = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS,new String[]{  KEY_PH_NO}, KEY_PH_NO+"=?",null, null, null, null);
  // return contact
  return contacts;
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

You should put the LogCat output that shows the exception StackTrace.

What I can spot in the code that it seems that you are missing

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >`

Comment: :thank you for your comment i solve that FC problem......can u tell me how can i access my database value to broadcast receiver activity...i cant read that on there...plse go through it..my code is..public Cursor getContact() 
 {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  
  Cursor contacts = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS,new String[]{  KEY_PH_NO}, KEY_PH_NO+"=?",null, null, null, null);
  // return contact
  return contacts;
  
 }